# FireFox & Selenium not working on specific version

Tags: c#, selenium, firefox

In a project, we have exact guidelines, which Selenium & FireFox Versions to run for UI Tests:
 - FireFox: 33.1 (some have 33.1.1, which works also)
 - NuGet Selenium.WebDriver 3.3.0
 - NuGet Selenium.Support 3.3.0

The FireFoxWebDriver is initialized like this:

```
var firefoxDirectory = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\";
var driverExecutableFileName = "firefox.exe";
var profileManager = new FirefoxProfileManager();
var profile = profileManager.GetProfile("default");

profile.EnableNativeEvents = false;

profile.SetPreference("intl.accept_languages", "en-US");
profile.SetPreference("browser.download.folderList", 2);
profile.SetPreference("browser.download.dir", "C:\\Temp");

profile.SetPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "text/csv,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet,application/octet-stream");

var defaultPath = $"{firefoxDirectory}{driverExecutableFileName}";
var options = new FirefoxOptions
{
    Profile = profile,
    UseLegacyImplementation = true
};

var service = FirefoxDriverService.CreateDefaultService(firefoxDirectory, driverExecutableFileName);

if (File.Exists(defaultPath))
{
    options.BrowserExecutableLocation = defaultPath;
}

var fireFoxDriver = new FirefoxDriver(service, options, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));

return fireFoxDriver;
```

My problem: It works on every other developer machine, but on mine, the following happens:
As soon as

```
var fireFoxDriver = new FirefoxDriver(service, options, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
```

Is hit, an empty FireFox window opens, but then it stops until the Timeout is reached. The length of the timeout doesn't matter, Selenium just doesn't seem to connect.
I uninstalled FireFox, the NuGet cache etc., imported the default-profile from other developers and checked all topics regarding that problem, but most topics are related to version incompatibility, which can't be the problem, since other devs have the same environment.
Are there other known issues or possibilities, what on my machine could influence this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

add this two lines to configuration

profile.SetPreference("browser.startup.homepage_override.mstone", "ignore");
profile.SetPreference("startup.homepage_welcome_url.additional", "about:blank");